# Javascript: button to convert test score into letter grade

Tags: javascript, html

Output is always 'F' even if testScore = 80.
This is the script

```
<script>
    function testScore(){
        var testScore = document.getElementById(score);
        if (testScore >=90){
            alert('A');
        } else if (testScore >=80) {
            alert('B');
        } else if (testScore >=70) {
            alert('C');
        } else if (testScore >=60) {
            alert('D');
        } else {
            alert('F');
    }
    }
</script>
```

Input, I ask user to enter a number grade, then a button below that to convert the number grade to letter grade after user clicks it.

```
<input type="number" id="score">
<button onclick="testScore(score)"> Calculate </button>
```

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Should be `var testScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('score').value)`

Comment: Looks like you mean `document.getElementById("score")`... also you want to get the `value` from the element, not the element itself.

Comment: I tried adding input with value="score" and document.getElementById("score") both single and double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    function testScore(){
        var testScore = document.getElementById("score").value;
        if (testScore >=90){
            alert('A');
        } else if (testScore >=80) {
            alert('B');
        } else if (testScore >=70) {
            alert('C');
        } else if (testScore >=60) {
            alert('D');
        } else {
            alert('F');
        }
    }
</script>
```

You need to get value present in `control`. Your code is getting `control` itself but not value.

Comment: Oh I see, you need to add ".value" to get the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Change a few things

1. Add some qotes to the onclick because you are searching for a string named "score".
2. Same as 1 but for the function testScore. You are searching for the text string id.
3. Add .value to the testScore function when getting the value of the input. 
   If you dont its like you are getting the input element object as a whole and not just the value that is written.

```js
function testScore(){
    
        var testScore = document.getElementById("score").value;
        
        if (testScore >= 90){
            alert('A');
        } else if (testScore >= 80) {
            alert('B');
        } else if (testScore >= 70) {
            alert('C');
        } else if (testScore >= 60) {
            alert('D');
        } else {
            alert('F');
    }
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="score">
<button onclick="testScore('score')"> Calculate </button>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to elaborating the answer. I wish I can upvote all answers but, unfortunately I have less than 15 points. This is going to be ingrained in my brain, all the efforts are really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- set `score` as `string`.
- you missing the element `value`.

```js
  ...
  function testScore(){
    var testScore = document.getElementById("score").value;
    ...
```

Note: if score is a global variable with the value of "score" then ignore the first thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function testScore(){
        var testScore = document.getElementById("score").value;
        if (testScore >=90){
            alert('A');
        } else if (testScore >=80) {
            alert('B');
        } else if (testScore >=70) {
            alert('C');
        } else if (testScore >=60) {
            alert('D');
        } else {
            alert('F');
        }
    }
</script>
```

You need to get value of the id. Furthermore, I do not believe you need the arguement within the button `onclick` method.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't need the score in onclick="testScore(score)"